# Background image for an empty flex child not displaying in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have two divs that I want to position side-by-side. One contains an image, one contains text.

Because the height of the text div will change depending on the width of the browser, I would like to use flexbox and background-size: cover to ensure the image is always the same height as the text div next to it.

I have managed to successfully do this in Chrome, Safari and Firefox in the following manner:

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.your-perfect-colours .content .image{
  background-image: url(/images/your-perfect-colours.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 62%;
}

.your-perfect-colours .text{
  order: 1;
  width: 38%;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-perfect-colours">
  <div class="content flexbox-container">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Your Perfect Colours</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ligula orci, varius in vulputate eu, lobortis a magna. Nunc a lectus ipsum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec pulvinar velit purus, vel consectetur risus laoreet a. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi quis efficitur arcu, et pharetra massa. Nullam sed diam purus.</p>
      <button>Find out more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in the following in the browser:

[image]

When the browser is resized, the image correctly adjusts its position to cover the size of the div.

However, I have used Browserstack to show me a screenshot from Internet Explorer and it's not loading the image:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious or is this an IE quirk? The fact this works in three other browsers seems to point the finger at IE, but I'd like to get some input on this to see if I can get this working.

Thanks.

Comment: Luke did you find the fix for this? Im facing the exact same problem in IE9 - Thanks

Comment: Ended up having to force the div to be the same height as the image - but using a percentage rather than a fixed value so it's always right regardless of screen width. CSS is here: http://imgur.com/a/Hq20P Link to the formula to know which percentage to use for padding (depending on your image dimensions) is here: http://andyshora.com/css-image-container-padding-hack.html (in the green box).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Luke! I ended up coming across this js fiddle that seems to work well also. Here is the link: http://fiddle.jshell.net/roine/wKmNA/4/just in case anyones else has this issue and i up-voted your question.